# Domain override module in drupal 7

Tags: domain-access

I have a main site with "domain access" module. It has 5 multilingual sub sites with subdomain(single database). 
I want to publish content from the main site to the subsites. This is already working good with send to affiliates.
But I want some admins on the subdomain to edit some content and it should reflect on that subdomain only
i.e It should not update content in main site.In drupal6 I found module "[domain override](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_override/)" 
How I can acheive this in drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Use [Node clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) module and remove the domains for which you don't want to publish the content.

This is what Node clone modules does:

> The clone module allows users to make a copy of an existing item of
>   site content (a node) and then edit that copy. The authorship is set
>   to the current user, the menu and url aliases are reset, and the words
>   **"Clone of"** are inserted into the title to remind you that you are not
>   editing the original content.

And this is what Domain override module does:

> Provides an "Override" tab on node pages that removes the current
>   domain from the node's domain access, **clones the node**, and publishes
>   the clone to only the current domain.

Comment: Thank you This is not expected one.we want override the content with same node based on sub domains

Comment: But the Domain Override module does the same, please check first point from features on project page of Domain override module. 

It says, "Provides an "Override" tab on node pages that removes the current domain from the node's domain access, clones the node, and publishes the clone to only the current domain."

Comment: Domain Override is not available for Drupal 7.

Comment: I mean both modules do the same task of cloning the node, only difference is Domain override removes all other domains from the new content and assigns current domain only.